# Macro on called workbook intermittent with it's function

Tags: vba, excel

What I have is a macro that is designed to open other workbooks and refresh the contents within those workbooks. All of these work except one of them is intermittent, and by that I mean most times it works exactly as required, but randomly it will bring up an error stating the macro cannot be found. I haven't found so far a point which I can pinpoint where it does this so it has been difficult to debug.

below is the code:

```
Call Shell("K:\ASA_Reporting\Audits\MDA\ListCompletedAudits.bat")

' This wait has been added to allow the command to run in Console
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:10"))

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Bits n Pieces").Range("G14").Value = "True"

Dim wb1 As Workbook

'This is to update the 5S Audit Dashboard
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("K:\ASA_Reporting\Audits\Audit Dashboard v002.xlsb", True, False, , , "password")

Application.Run "'Audit Dashboard v002.xlsb'!Refresh5S"

wb1.Close savechanges:=True

Stop
```

The point which has a commented out section "This is to update the 5S Audit Dashboard" is the code which is where the issue is occurring. The section above that in regards to the waiting 10 seconds is to correct a different issue which is unrelated to the 5S.

I know that the Macro is correct as it works on the 5S workbook, and it does work most times through my updater, but as I've said on occasion is brings up an error stating the macro does not exist.

I have checked the code what is being called (shown below) but I cannot any errors in this.

```
Sub Refresh5S()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim datasheet As Worksheet
Set datasheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Sheet")

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set wb=Workbooks.Open("\\bosch.com\dfsrb\dfsuk\loc\wo\dept\service\ASA_Reporting\Audits
\5S Audit Master v2.xlsx", True, True)
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Counts")

datasheet.Range("W6:Z21").Value = ws.Range("B5:E20").Value
datasheet.Range("AB6:AC400").Value = ws.Range("H5:I399").Value
datasheet.Range("AD6:AG400").Value = ws.Range("K5:N399").Value
datasheet.Range("AH6:AH400").Value = ws.Range("O5:O399").Value

wb.Close False

MsgBox "Thank you for your patience." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "The figures 
should update in a few seconds.", vbInformation
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

I thought I had found the answer on a Microsoft help page titled "Macro in Excel Stops After A Workbook.Open Command" However that was for when you press the shift key, and that is not happening in this instance, it is being left to it's on devices.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/555263

Does anyone have any idea why it randomly decides the Macro in the 5S workbook doesn't exist?

Edit:
Tried the below and it worked for the day without issue, then today the problem came back with the following error:

[image: Runtime 1004 error]

The code has not been changed except for the suggestions below, which worked for a day.

Comment: Try a `Do Until Application.Ready = True: DoEvents: Loop` before `Application.Run "'Audit Dashboard v002.xlsb'!Refresh5S"` to make sure that loading of the workbook is finished before you run the macro.

Comment: Along with @Peh suggestion, I would also check the workbook did open (i.e. something like: `If Not IsEmpty(wb1) Then`. Also, as you have already qualified your workbook object, you can use that to get workbook name (i.e. `Application.Run "' & wb1.Name & "'!Refresh5S"`). Amongst other things, it helps to avoid any spelling mistakes in file name

Comment: Just an update found that the issue seems to only happen with Windows 10 and Excel 2016. Seems to not happen with older versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the end with Excel, as the latest updates of Office have now resolved this issue.